# Is Alex Danvers' superhero suit intended to represent a comic book hero?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

In the fifth season of *Supergirl*, Alex Danvers leaves her position as the head of the D.E.O. and takes up vigilantism. Towards the end of the season, she is given a superhero outfit by Martian Manhunter. Previously in the series, Jimmy Olsen takes up the mantle of Guardian, an identity used by several people in the comics. Is Danvers intended to represent the Arrowverse's version of a known comic book character?
[image: Imagine this but with a hood]

Comment: FWIW, people think that it's more based off of the suit she wears in "Alex in Wonderland". Alternately, "Mia Smoak's Green Arrow suit" is another guess.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots wouldn't that be the start of an answer?

Comment: @BenBarden The keyword being _start_. It’s not really an answer yet but a comment... hence it being posted as a comment.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but it strikes me as being reminiscent of [Nightwing](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/IT7EBzc0AzbTIA0U6kppfs2qeNU=/0x0:763x1046/1400x1400/filters:focal(304x287:426x409):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/53393565/nightwing_building.0.jpg). Especially with the dark circles around her eyes.